# error when trying to post a comment, on post route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to backend development and When I post a comment I get following error in console (I know this code is a mess but in vs code looks better lol)

```
    { comments:
   [ { _id: 5b570970beff3674bc8e851d,
       text: 'This place is great, but I wish there was internet',
       author: 'Homer',
       __v: 0 } ],
  _id: 5b570970beff3674bc8e851a,
  name: 'Cloud\'s Rest',
  image: 'https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3795/10131087094_c1c0a1c859.jpg',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum',
  __v: 1 }
{ CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 5b570970beff3674bc8e851a" at path "_id" for model "Campground"
    at new CastError (G:\webdevbootcamp\yelpcomp_project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:29:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (G:\webdevbootcamp\yelpcomp_project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:158:13)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (G:\webdevbootcamp\yelpcomp_project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:724:12)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (G:\webdevbootcamp\yelpcomp_project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1113:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (G:\webdevbootcamp\yelpcomp_project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1103:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (G:\webdevbootcamp\yelpcomp_project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1082:15)
    at cast (G:\webdevbootcamp\yelpcomp_project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:303:32)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (G:\webdevbootcamp\yelpcomp_project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3355:12)
    at model.Query.Query._castConditions (G:\webdevbootcamp\yelpcomp_project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1327:10)
    at model.Query.Query._findOne (G:\webdevbootcamp\yelpcomp_project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1552:8)
    at process.nextTick (G:\webdevbootcamp\yelpcomp_project\node_modules\kareem\index.js:333:33)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:112:11)
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 5b570970beff3674bc8e851a" at path "_id" for model "Campground"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '" 5b570970beff3674bc8e851a"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: ' 5b570970beff3674bc8e851a',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined,
  model:
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: [Map], _posts: [Map] },
     base:
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Array],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
        plugins: [Array] },
     modelName: 'Campground',
     model: [Function: model],
     db:
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Mongoose],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        options: null,
        otherDbs: [],
        relatedDbs: {},
        states: [Object],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: false,
        _connectionOptions: [Object],
        client: [MongoClient],
        name: 'yelp_camp',
        '$initialConnection': [Promise],
        db: [Db] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     '$appliedMethods': true,
     '$appliedHooks': true,
     schema:
      Schema {
        obj: [Object],
        paths: [Object],
        aliases: {},
        subpaths: [Object],
        virtuals: [Object],
        singleNestedPaths: {},
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        methodOptions: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        query: {},
        childSchemas: [],
        plugins: [Array],
        s: [Object],
        _userProvidedOptions: {},
        options: [Object],
        '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
        _requiredpaths: [],
        _indexedpaths: [] },
     collection:
      NativeCollection {
        collection: [Collection],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'campgrounds',
        collectionName: 'campgrounds',
        conn: [NativeConnection],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false,
        emitter: [EventEmitter] },
     Query: { [Function] base: [Query] },
     '$__insertMany': [Function],
     '$init': Promise { [Circular], catch: [Function] } } }
```

Following are the files I am working with

**app.js**

```
    var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Campground = require("./models/campgrounds"),
    Comment = require("./models/comment"),
    seedDB = require("./seeds")

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/yelp_camp");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
seedDB();

/*Campground.create(
    {
        name: "Granite Hill",
        image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1445308394109-4ec2920981b1?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=73115e54fa3d099fcb2d92ccf12eee41&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80",
        description: "This is a huge granite hill, no bathrooms, no water. Beautiful Granite!"
    },
    function(err,campground){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("NEWLY CREATED CAMPGROUND: ");
            console.log(campground);
        }
    }
);  */

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("landing");
});

//INDEX - show all campgrounds
app.get("/campgrounds", function (req, res) {
    //get all campgrounds from DB
    Campground.find({}, function (err, campgrounds) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("campgrounds/index", {
                campgrounds: campgrounds
            });
        }
    });
});

app.get("/campgrounds/new", function (req, res) {
    res.render("campgrounds/new");
});

//post route for campgrounds
app.post("/campgrounds", function (req, res) {
    //get data from form and add to campgrounds array
    var name = req.body.name;
    var image = req.body.image;
    var desc = req.body.description;
    var newCampground = {
        name: name,
        image: image,
        description: desc
    }
    //create a new campground and save it to database
    Campground.create(newCampground, function (err, newlyCreated) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //redirect back to campgrounds page
            res.redirect("/campgrounds");
        }
    });
});

// SHOW - shows more info about one campground
app.get("/campgrounds/:id", function (req, res) {
    //find the campground with provided id
    Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function (err, foundCampground) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(foundCampground);
            //render show template with that campground
            res.render("campgrounds/show", {
                campground: foundCampground
            });
        }
    });
});

    //===================================================
    //             ROUTES FOR COMMENTS
    //===================================================

    app.get("/campgrounds/:id/comments/new", function (req, res) {
        // find campgrounds by id
        Campground.findById(req.params.id, function (err, campground) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.render("comments/new", {
                    campground: campground
                });
            }
        });
    });

app.post("/campgrounds/:id/comments", function (req, res) {
    //lookup campground using ID
    Campground.findById(req.params.id, function (err, campground) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/campgrounds");
        } else {
            Comment.create(req.body.comment, function (err, comment) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    campground.comments.push(comment);
                    campground.save();
                    res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    //create new comment
    //connect new comment to campground
    //redirect to campground show page
});


//tell app to liten on local host
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("yelpCamp server started");
});
```

**views>campgrounds>index.ejs**

```
<% include ../partials/header %>

    <div class="container">
        <header class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Welcome to YelpCamp</h1>
                <p>view our hand-picked camp grounds from all over the world</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="/campgrounds/new">Add New Campground</a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h3>Our Most Popular CampGrounds</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row text-center">
            <% campgrounds.forEach(function(campground){ %>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="<%= campground.image %>" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4><%= campground.name %></h4>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            <a href="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <%}); %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <% include ../partials/footer %>
```

**views>campgrounds>new.ejs**

```
<% include ../partials/header %>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="text-center">Create a New Campground</h1>
        <div style="width: 30%; margin: 25px auto;">
        <form action="/campgrounds" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="image" placeholder="image url">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" placeholder="description">
        </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit!</button>
        </form>
            <a href="/campgrounds">Go Back</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% include ../partials/footer %>
```

**views>campgrounds>show.ejs**

```
<% include ../partials/header %>

<h1>this is the show template</h1>
<p><%= campground.name %></p>
<img src="<%= campground.image %>">
<p><%= campground.description %></p>

<% campground.comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
    <p>
    <strong><%= comment.author %></strong> - <%= comment.text %></p>
<% }) %>
<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

**views>comments>new.ejs**

```
   <% include ../partials/header %>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="text-center">Add New Comment to <%= campground.name %></h1>
        <div style="width: 30%; margin: 25px auto;">
        <form action="/campgrounds/ <%= campground._id %>/comments" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="comments[text]" placeholder="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="comments[author]" placeholder="author">
        </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit!</button>
        </form>
            <a href="/campgrounds">Go Back</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% include ../partials/footer %>
```

**tried solutions**
- deleting database and creating new one

Update: after removing space I get redirected to corresponding campgrounds page but it does not update the comment and has another error which looks something like this ill try to solve it but help would be appreciated

```
{ comments:
   [ { _id: 5b571c8f30c81d36642d4aa6,
       text: 'This place is great, but I wish there was internet',
       author: 'Homer',
       __v: 0 } ],
  _id: 5b571c8f30c81d36642d4aa3,
  name: 'Cloud\'s Rest',
  image: 'https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3795/10131087094_c1c0a1c859.jpg',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum',
  __v: 1 }
{ comments:
   [ { _id: 5b571c8f30c81d36642d4aa6,
       text: 'This place is great, but I wish there was internet',
       author: 'Homer',
       __v: 0 },
     { _id: 5b571cba30c81d36642d4aac, __v: 0 } ],
  _id: 5b571c8f30c81d36642d4aa3,
  name: 'Cloud\'s Rest',
  image: 'https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3795/10131087094_c1c0a1c859.jpg',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum',
  __v: 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are inserting a space character after campgrounds in the line

```
<form action="/campgrounds/ <%= campground._id %>/comments" method="POST">
```

It even shows in the line `stringValue: '" 5b570970beff3674bc8e851a"',`

Comment: your point was right thanks now i am faced with another error ill update it in code

Comment: It doesn't update the comment for some reason I get redirected to campground page but it doesn't update